# With FluentValidation check that one are more property are populated

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

With FluentValidation I need to validate that at lest one of five properties is populated. Lets say I have this class:

```
public class Something
{
    public string Required1 { get; set; }
    public string Required2 { get; set; }
    public string Optional1 { get; set; }
    public string Optional2 { get; set; }
    public string Optional3 { get; set; }
    public string Optional4 { get; set; }
    public string Optional5 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a validator with this constructor:

```
public SomethingValidator()
{
    RuleFor(e => e.Required1)
        .NotEmpty();

    RuleFor(e => e.Required2)
        .NotEmpty();

    RuleFor(e => e.Required1)
        .Must((e, r1) =>
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional1) 
            || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional2)
            || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional3)
            || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional4)
            || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional5)
        );
}
```

It works but it seem kinda funky that I'm add a rule to a property when really I want a rule just for the object. The property express in the third `RuleFor()` could be anything. It's not required in the `Must()` method.

Is there a better built in rule type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ommit that property when you start from `RuleFor(e => e)` just passing the target object.

```
RuleFor(e => e)
    .Must(e => 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional1)
        || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional2)
        || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional3)
        || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional4)
        || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Optional5)
        );
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that. It better then specifying an unused property but it's still not ideal. It does seem to be the best option currently available.